# bash, nested commands and redirects

Tags: bash, redirect, command, nested, pipe

I am trying to track the CPU usage of a process using a command like this:

```
    top -b -d 1 | grep myprocess.exe
```

Next, I would like to redirect this to a log file, e.g.

```
    top -b -d 1 | grep myprocess.exe > output.log
```

Now, this does not actually work because it thinks I am grepping myprocess.exe > output.log
instead of myprocess.exe

Does anybody know how I can get this redirect to work?

Comment: Why do you think it's `grep`ping for the redirect? The redirect is interpreted by `bash` and doesn't make it to the process name

Comment: `top -b -d 1 | grep postgres > output.log` works on my machine (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS).

Comment: Perhaps that is true, but it still doesn't explain why output.log is empty when I run the second command.

Comment: What environment are you using? (distro, command shell)

Answer (score 2):

> Now, this does not actually work because it thinks I am grepping `myprocess.exe > output.log` instead of `myprocess.exe`

Wrong. All should be fine. The 1st example executes the pipeline with `stdout` set to your terminal (thus you see the output, but nothing is written to the file). The 2nd example executes the pipeline with `stdout` set to `output.log` (thus you don't see output, but it will go right in your file).

If you want the output written to both, you need another process that gets your previous pipeline's `stdout` as `stdin`, and duplicates it. Like:

```
previous_pipeline | tee output.log
```

`tee` will print on stdout what it gets on `stdin` (So for `stdout`, everything is the same as before), but additionally open another file (given as cmdline arg) and write a copy to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tee`:

```
top -b -d 1 | grep myprocess.exe | tee output.log
```

If you want it to show no output:

```
top -b -d 1 | grep myprocess.exe | tee output.log > /dev/null
```

Comment: So tee does not seem to work for me.  I get the same result as before (e.g. output.log is empty).

Comment: Sorry, but the 2nd example does essentially the same as OP's 2nd example. The 1st example should be the solution.

Comment: Actually, I tried the first example above and that still gave an empty output.log.  Any ideas?

Comment: @user788171: On my system, `tee` seems to collect a bit of output and write in bigger bursts (while `grep` simply writes as soon as it can, so the `-d 1` option to `top` had effect, it now hasn't). You can be happy with it, or go with the file-only solution (try `tail -f FILE | less`) on a file that is being written to.